# How to use substring to split a filename and generate a .csv file with Java?

Tags: java, csv, filenames

I have a folder with several thousands of files from where i which to extract filenames and export them to a `.csv` file. The filenames contain 4 informations that i need to put in 3 different columns in the exported `.csv` file.

I have already wrote some code with Java and it has been working for me at some point except that some informations in the filename are skipped.

Here is the code i wrote:

```
package PR;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class PR {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        final File folder = new File("./pack");

           PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new File("results.csv"));

           for (final File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()) {
            if (!fileEntry.isDirectory()) { 
                String filename = fileEntry.getName();


                String date = filename.substring(0, 17);
                System.out.println(date);

                int index = filename.indexOf("_", 18);
                String pack = filename.substring(18,index);
                System.out.println(pack);


                int index2 = filename.indexOf("_", index+2);
                String dir = filename.substring(index+4, index2);
                System.out.println(dir);


                String last = filename.substring(index2 + 1, filename.indexOf('.', index2 + 1));
                System.out.println(last);
                System.out.println(fileEntry.getName());

                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.append(date);
                sb.append(",");
                sb.append(pack);
                sb.append(",");                 
                sb.append(dir); 
                sb.append(",");
                sb.append(last + "\n");
                pw.write(sb.toString());
            }
        }
        pw.close();
```

The filenames i have are exactly as follows:

```
20180731020925524_nr37188r2_02_Hi78-red-out
```

And the output .csv file i want is like this:

```
20180731020925524,nr37188r2,02,Hi78-red-out
```

Is there anyone that can help me solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `String.replace()` method to simply replace the underscores with commas, if those are your separators. [see here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(char,%20char))

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    final File folder = new File("./pack");
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new File("results.csv"));

    for (final File fileEntry : folder.listFiles())
        if (!fileEntry.isDirectory())
            pw.println(fileEntry.getName().replace('_', ','));
    pw.close();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that works like a charm, it was really quick resolved